# Getting empty cURL response with status OK 200

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm using cURL to make some API calls, and everything worked fine until today. The only thing that changed is that I've added some content to the db that the API returns. The interesting thing is that I get a http_status of 200, but an empty response. What's even stranger is that some other calls do work, so my guess is that it's somehow related to the size of the response.

When running that same request from some webservice like Postman, I can see that the API in fact does return data, it's only on the server that the cURL returns empty array.

I make a cURL request like this:

```
    $curl = curl_init(API_URL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
          array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
```

The `curl_getinfo` for the empty response returns something like this:

```
Array
(
    [url] => api_url_to_which_im_sending
    [content_type] => application/json;charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 157
    [request_size] => 219
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.656782
    [namelookup_time] => 3.9E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.121461
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.121504
    [size_upload] => 83
    [size_download] => 17355
    [speed_download] => 26424
    [speed_upload] => 126
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 83
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.292595
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => someip
    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => someotherip
    [local_port] => someport
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

The only notable difference to the API calls that actually return some data are the:

```
[size_download] => 17355
[speed_download] => 26424
```

lines, which are a lot smaller (300 - 800).

So my question is, since I'm guessing that it's somehow size related, what server setting is responsible for this, and how can I increase allowed response size?

Comment: Are you calling your own api? An external API? Multiple APIs? Do you reset your cURL object after each call or attempt to re-use the same connection? Are you calling the api many times or just a few?

Comment: Just one API that I don't have access to. For testing purposes, I just run one API call, the one that's giving me trouble, usually I run 3-4 at the same time. Still even when running that just one through cURL i get empty response. The same call returns data when using webservice to post to API url.